# Kotlin : Casting an object to Generic class

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, interface, fragment

How get the type of a Generic class and cast an object to it?

I want to use this function to pass an Interface class:

```
protected fun <T> getInteraction(): T {
        return when {
            context is T -> context
            parentFragment is T -> parentFragment as T
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("not implemented interaction")
        }
    }
```

and use it like:

```
 private var interaction: ISigninInteraction? = null

 override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        interaction = getInteraction<ISigninInteraction>()

 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Kotlin, Java and JVM do have types erasure when Generics are implemented. Generics are not visible at the bytecode level. It means, you cannot use type parameters, e.g. `T`, directly in the function code.

Kotlin adds support for `reified` generics, which helps here. You may declare the function like

```
inline fun <reified T> getIt() : T {
  ...
}
```

With the help of `reified` and `inline` it will be possible to cast to `T` and return it.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters

The second alternative is to follow a Java practice - add the `Class<T>` parameter to the function and use `Class#cast` to cast to `T` instead.

You may combine the `reified inline` function with the approach like:

```
inline fun <reified T> getIt() = getIt(T::class.java)
```